# Is snappy decompression supported by Vert.x 4.2.5?

Tags: vert.x, snappy

I use Vert.x `HttpServer` created like this:

`vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions().setDecompressionSupported(true));`

My client can send two type of messages to this server:

1. message compressed by `gzip` (`java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` is used for compression)
2. message compressed by `snappy` (`org.xerial.snappy.SnappyFramedOutputStream` is used for compression)

I expect that incoming message will be decompressed automatically by underlying netty server. It is working for gzip messages, however it is **not** working for snappy messages. Snappy messages are not decompressed automatically.

I send following HTTP headers with gzip messages:

- Content-Encoding: gzip
- Content-Type: application/gzip

I send following HTTP headers with snappy messages:

- Content-Encoding: x-snappy-framed
- Content-Type: application/x-snappy-framed

Is it possible to enable snappy decompression for HTTP server in Vert.x 4.2.5?
If not, is it possible to extend Vert.x so netty's `SnappyFrameDecoder` will be used?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.2.5, it is not possible. There is a draft pull request that should be released in 4.3.0: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/pull/4262